# Unresolved Import for flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need help... I'm not sure what is the problem. flask and sql-alchemy is installed. I've looked at other solutions across the internet like checking the settings and editing it. e.g.
"python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python",
Though for some reason only flask_sqlalchemy seems to be an unresolved import...

Thank you for any sort of help/advice.

[image to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRsUa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you installed Flask and SQLAlchemy. By that, I understand you did

```
pip install Flask
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

But to use Flask-SQLAlchemy, you need to download it separately by doing

```
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```